# Move the line before the table along with the table if the line appears on the page preceding the table

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have captions for tables in our Word documents that do not behave like captions and act as "Normal" word styles. These captions sometimes appear on the preceding page of the table.

There are hundreds of documents and may be a million instances of captions in those documents. The documents were imported from an old source system to a new source system using a script, which didn't do the job as expected.

I would like if such captions exist on the preceding page, they are removed from the page and shown before the table on the same page.

The logic that I want to use:

1. Find a table
2. Find the page number of the table
3. Find the first instance of "Normal" paragraph style just before the table
4. Find the page number of the "Normal" Paragraph style
5. Only if the page number of the first instance of the "Normal" Paragraph style is less than the page number of the table by 1, then move the entire instance to the next page just before the table
6. Do this for all tables.

So far I could only manage to write this code:

```vb
Dim tblNew As Table
Dim oPara As Paragraph
Dim oRng As Range
Dim PageNo As Integer
Dim PageNoCap As Integer

For Each tblNew In ActiveDocument.Tables
PageNo = tblNew.Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Comment: Your problem is simply down to the incorrect use of styles. By having a separate style for those “captions” you would need only to set the “Keep with next” property and it would stay with the table automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by fixing the incorrect use of styles. The code below applies the Caption style to demonstrate the principle.

Using code to compensate for not using Word correctly in the first place is a bad idea, but if you have existing documents that you need to correct could be a useful temporary measure.

```
Sub ApplyStyleToTableCaptions()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim oRng As Range

    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleCaption).ParagraphFormat
        If Not .KeepWithNext Then .KeepWithNext = True
    End With
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Set oRng = tbl.Range
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        oRng.Move wdParagraph, -1
        oRng.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style = wdStyleCaption
    Next tbl
End Sub
```

Comment: I understand and that is a common resolution we have in our team, however, there are hundreds of documents and may be a million instances of captions in those document. The documents were imported from an old source system to a new source system using a script, which didn't do the job as expected. Now we are left with this and need to give the documents to our customers and time is something we may not find. Changing the styles will be a gradual process. But until then we will still need a fix. I appreciate your  fix. Will modify and use it to see things can be sorted. Thanks once again

Comment: @ChrisJoseph - If those documents don't use styles at all then you can easily use the code above. Simply add in the settings to re-define the Caption style to match your requirements and you have your fix, with the bonus that if you ever need to edit the caption formatting in future it will be a much simpler task.

Comment: The captions use the "Normal" Style in word docs, which  is also applied to other paragraph components and images. I can use the macro you suggested, but we have found instances where there are no captions as well. in which case, the prior paragraph will get converted into captions. We also need to do this for caption of images, but since both of them are in "Normal" formats, not sure how to identify them using vba

Comment: @ChrisJoseph - You can apply the same principle. Loop through the `.InlineShapes` collection and apply the style to the caption paragraph. Obviously, you need to analyse the documents first to identify where the caption is relative to the image, and if the document layout isn't consistent you'll need an editing process too. You can at least use code to do the bulk of the editing.

Comment: Your solution regarding this works great. after giving the captions the "Captions" style, they automatically adjust with the images and tables and are not left hanging anymore. Plus they look great. Thanks for all your help once again.